# My skin changes back to default when I join mini-games in servers

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

To upload my skins, I go to the Skindex, click upload and change from minecraft.net. I've never had any trouble doing this until 3 days ago...

My skin changes perfectly fine when I join *some* servers, but when I join a mini-game, like in [**Mineplex**](http://www.mineplex.com/) or other servers with mini games, my skin changes back to default. It remains that way when I exit the mini-game too! On *some* servers, my skin won't change at all. It stays default. Why is this? I've tried downloading the skin and then uploading it to minecraft.net. But that doesn't help... I've tried different skins too. They all go back to steve. I can't wear any skins...

Comment: It's fully possible that, even though you see yourself as Steve in your inventory, other players see your skin. Try restarting and updating your game. In addition you can check this site to see the status of all of Mojang's servers (one is skins): http://xpaw.ru/mcstatus/

Comment: This is a little broad. You shouldn't ask about specific servers as they are not hosted by us. Instead, ask a server mod/admin.

Comment: As for your over-all skin problem, it's a little hard to understand even with the grammar edit I did... 0_0

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Mojang's servers are up. Check [Mojang's help website](https://help.mojang.com/) and there should be a tab that says "Minecraft skins". If it is up, it will say "This service is healthy. All is good!", but offline will say "This service is down! We are doing our very best to resolve the issue as soon as possible".